# Is it possible not to output relation column when using APOC.export?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

```
MATCH (m:computer)

WITH collect(DISTINCT m) AS M
CALL apoc.export.csv.data( M, [], null, {stream:true, batchSize:100}) YIELD data as mdata
```

For such a query, even if just for export nodes, without relationships, it still gives the following field with all empty values:

```
 _start
  _end
  _type
```

And it's hard to filter out them in the process. Is there a parameter to control this?

ADDITIONS:

```
MATCH (m:SportsTeam)-[r:hasMember]-(n)
WITH collect(DISTINCT m) AS M, collect(DISTINCT n) AS N, collect(r) as R
CALL apoc.export.csv.data( M, [], null, {stream:true}) YIELD data
WITH apoc.text.replace(data, '(?:,"_start","_end","_type"|,,,)(?=\n)', '') AS mdata
CALL apoc.export.csv.data( N, [], null, {stream:true}) YIELD data as ndata
WITH apoc.text.replace(data, '(?:,"_start","_end","_type"|,,,)(?=\n)', '') AS ndata
CALL apoc.export.csv.data( [], R, null, {stream:true}) YIELD data as rdata
RETURN mdata, ndata, rdata
```

What I am doing here is to output the node M, node N and relation R into 3 different files. After I added the 2 replace functions to get rid of the last 3 columns, it reports this error:

```
neobolt.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: Variable `N` not defined (line 5, column 28 (offset: 282))
"CALL apoc.export.csv.data( N, [], null, {stream:true}) YIELD data as ndata"
```

Does the CALL and WITH can't be used in a row like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the APOC function [apoc.text.replace](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/misc/text-functions/) to modify the CSV string to remove the unwanted rows:

```
MATCH (c:computer)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT c) AS cs
CALL apoc.export.csv.data(cs, [], null, {stream:true, batchSize:100}) YIELD data
WITH apoc.text.replace(data, '(?:,"_start","_end","_type"|,,,)(?=\n)', "") AS newData
... // use newData, which does not have the last 3 columns
```

Since the 3 columns you don't want are at the end of each row, the regular expression `(?:,"_start","_end","_type"|,,,)(?=\n)` matches the unwanted text at the end of each row (whether the header row or a data row).

[UPDATE]

With respect to the `ADDITIONS` issues: a [WITH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/) clause will drop any variables not specified by the clause, so `N` was not being carried forward. Also, you had other issues. This should fix up all the issues:

```
MATCH (m:SportsTeam)-[r:hasMember]-(n)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT m) AS M, COLLECT(DISTINCT n) AS N, COLLECT(r) as R
CALL apoc.export.csv.data( M, [], null, {stream:true}) YIELD data
WITH apoc.text.replace(data, '(?:,"_start","_end","_type"|,,,)(?=\n)', '') AS mdata, N, R
CALL apoc.export.csv.data( N, [], null, {stream:true}) YIELD data
WITH apoc.text.replace(data, '(?:,"_start","_end","_type"|,,,)(?=\n)', '') AS ndata, mdata, R
CALL apoc.export.csv.data( [], R, null, {stream:true}) YIELD data AS rdata
RETURN mdata, ndata, rdata
```

Comment: I also want to remove the first '_id' & '_label' columns. How to modify it a bit? I tried adding as "_id","_labels""_start","_end","_type"|,,,,,, but it didn't work.

Comment: My solution only applies to the last columns (that also have no data). You will have to come up with a more complex regular expression for your new use case.

Comment: Please see the above additions regarding the replacement operation. My situation is a bit more complex.

Comment: Technically, you *should* have created a new question, as the new issues are not the same as the original ones. But see my updated answer.